# Using CTE in Oracle SQL (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected)

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, window-functions

Question: from the following table containing a list of dates and items ordered, write a query to return the most frequent item ordered on each date. Return multiple items in the case of a tie.

Input for question in Oracle SQL

```
create table items(dates varchar2(200), item VARCHAR2(200));

insert into items values ('01-01-20', 'apple');
insert into items values ('01-01-20', 'apple');
insert into items values ('01-01-20', 'pear');
insert into items values ('01-01-20', 'pear');
insert into items values ('01-02-20', 'pear');
insert into items values ('01-02-20', 'pear');
insert into items values ('01-02-20', 'pear');
insert into items values ('01-02-20', 'orange');
```

This is the code I am trying to execute. However, I get an error

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Can someone please help?

```
select dates, item
from 
(
SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION by dates ORDER BY item_count DESC) AS date_rank
FROM 
(
SELECT dates, item, count(*) AS item_count
FROM items
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1))
where date_rank=1;
```

Comment: I don't see any CTE in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replace `*` in your sub query with `dates, items` and changed group by clause from `group by 1,2` to `group by dates, items`. It's working.

But I would suggest to use query#2 which is more readable in my opinion and easy to change in future.

```
 create table items(dates varchar2(200), item VARCHAR2(200));

 insert into items values ('01-01-20', 'apple');

 insert into items values ('01-01-20', 'apple');

 insert into items values ('01-01-20', 'pear');

 insert into items values ('01-01-20', 'pear');

 insert into items values ('01-02-20', 'pear');

 insert into items values ('01-02-20', 'pear');

 insert into items values ('01-02-20', 'pear');

 insert into items values ('01-02-20', 'orange');
```

Query#1:

```
select dates, item
     from 
     (
     SELECT dates,item, rank() OVER (PARTITION by dates ORDER BY item_count DESC) AS date_rank
     FROM 
     (
     SELECT dates, item, count(*) AS item_count
     FROM items
     GROUP BY dates, item
     ORDER BY dates) ) 
     where date_rank=1;
```

Output:

| DATES | ITEM |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-20 | apple |
| 01-01-20 | pear |
| 01-02-20 | pear |

Query#2:

```
 with cte (dates,item,date_rank) as
 (  
    SELECT dates, item,rank() OVER (PARTITION by dates ORDER BY count(*) DESC)  AS date_rank
    FROM items
    GROUP BY dates, item
    ORDER BY dates
 )
 select  dates,item from cte 
 where date_rank=1;
```

Output:

| DATES | ITEM |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-20 | apple |
| 01-01-20 | pear |
| 01-02-20 | pear |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a2c16a8b05456d0411a82bd6123afd5b)*

Comment: Hi Kazi, this is perfect. Can you please explain? What was my error?

Comment: @Ashima I have already revised my answer with explanation.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me why is it working with replacing * and 1 and 2? Any specific reason. Sorry I am trying to learn SQL from scratch, so this tip might be extremely useful.

Comment: Which version of oracle dbms you are using? You can also use items.* which is fine. Column numbers are permitted to use in order by clause but not in group by clause.

Comment: I am using the Oracle LIVE SQL console. https://livesql.oracle.com/

Comment: Same is true for column aliases: you can use them in order by clause but not in group by clause. You can look into execution order of oracle query. You are most welcome. Best wishes. Your effort deserves upvoting.